# Expanding a countif function down a column in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, countif

I'm trying to expand the following formula down a column using an array, which I understand doesn't work exactly with countif. I need this as the divisor in the column where I have the numerator expanding successfully down the column. Here is the function that works fine in each row:

```
=arrayformula(countifs(unique(if('All Data'!$B$2:$B=$A2,'All Data'!$A$2:$A,)),">="&edate(F$2,0),unique(if('All Data'!$B$2:$B=$A2,'All Data'!$A$2:$A,)),"<="&edate(F$2,1)))
```

I am trying to avoid copying the formulas all over the sheet, as it is rather large and would prefer it to work as an array where it gives me the count for a2 in row 2, a3 in row 3, a4 in row 4, etc, so I tried this formula, which doesn't work:

```
=arrayformula(countifs(unique(if('All Data'!$B$2:$B=$A2:$A,'All Data'!$A$2:$A,)),">="&edate(F$2,0),unique(if('All Data'!$B$2:$B=$A2:$A,'All Data'!$A$2:$A,)),"<="&edate(F$2,1)))
```

Is there a workaround I can use to get this expanding for me?

Thank you!

Comment: Could you please share a copy of the spreadsheet you're working on?

Comment: I had to clear out the private data, so here is a skimmed-down version: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iy7xRjjABOT9L9wePjxWb2TS9yDp2lYP4iPOfXvH8vg/edit?usp=sharing

The sheet with the formula is "Class Totals"

Thank you!

Comment: Isn't current formula already expanding down through the column? Did you find the solution to this, or I'm missing something?

Comment: For some reason, it isn't. I found some articles/stack overflow questions that suggest countif can't do that as I set it up.I'm honestly not sure why though, as it seems to me it should work fine. It really hasn't been answered well anywhere I found similar questions, so maybe it just isn't possible? I've reverted to just copying the formula everywhere instead of having it expand down each column, so it's a solution of sorts.

Comment: Isn't this expanding down the column? https://i.imgur.com/O0UxYlT.png

Comment: The first part of the formula does, but I need the divisor, and for some reason, it isn't working. Can you see that in the separate formulas on the side? I've changed the access to "edit" so you can play with those formulas.

Comment: Can you explain what the divisor part is supposed to do? Don't just bring the formula, but explain what this formula is supposed to accomplish.

Comment: Sorry about that. The divisor is supposed to count the number of unique dates that a specific class name occurs on. The numerator counts (successfully) the number of students in a class in total. We need to divide this by the number of class occurrences to get the average number of students in the class overall for the month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could accomplish this with an Apps Script [custom function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions). To achieve this, follow these steps:

- In your spreadsheet, select **Tools > Script editor** to open a script bound to your file.
- Copy this function in the script editor, and save the project:

```js
function AVERAGE_STUDENTS(classes, monthIndex) {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("All Data");
  const data = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  const monthRows = data.filter(row => row[0].getMonth() + 1 == monthIndex);
  return classes.map(classy => {
    const classRows = monthRows.filter(row => row[1] == classy[0]);
    const totalStudents = classRows.length;
    const uniqueDates = new Set(classRows.map(element => JSON.stringify([element[0], element[1]]))).size;
    return totalStudents / uniqueDates;
  });
}
```

- Now, if you go back to your spreadsheet, you can use this function like any in-built one. You just have to provide the appropriate range for the classes (in this case it would be `A3:A18`) and the month index (for April, that's `4`), as you can see here:

[image]

#### Note:

- This function could also be modified in order to just call the function at `C1` and populate all months automatically.

#### Reference:

- [Custom Functions in Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)

Comment: Great idea, thank you! I wasn't even thinking over bringing another script into this, but that will work nicely.

Comment: I'm trying out this function and I realized, this isn't account for the year, is that correct? Some parts of your function are new to me, so could you help me update the code to also take the year into account? Thanks!

Comment: @Brian-RGYStudio Yes, it's only accounting for the month. You can use [getFullYear](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getFullYear) and pass the year you want to retrieve as parameter in order to filter rows according to year as well as month. Let me know if you need more pointers on this.